# Can select but not write/update to SQL server

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, mybatis, ibatis

as the title say I can read from the database but not insert nor update. I've checked in SQL Management and my user can read, write and is also DB owner. (dbo)

Im using MyBatis with JDBC towards Microsoft SQL Management Studio

```
sqlFunctions.InsertIntoUserDatabase(3, "Kar", "LEEE");


    public void InsertIntoUserDatabase(int id, String firsname, String lastname) {
    session = sqlConnection.GetSqlSessionFactory().openSession();
    if(CheckIfSessionIsOpen(session)) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setFirstName(firsname); employee.setLastName(lastname);
        mapper.InsertInUsers(employee);
    }
}

@Insert("INSERT INTO company(firstname,lastname) VALUES(#{firstName}, #{lastName})")
void InsertInUsers(Employee employee);
```

Employee is a normal getter and setter (int id, String firstname, String lastname)

```
    @Results({
        @Result(property = "firstName", column = "firstname"),
        @Result(property = "lastName", column = "lastname")
})
```

My SQL connection is opened as it should be, and no errors is being shown.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your transaction is read only which is default behavior.

You need to make it writable also e.g.

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
```

Regards,
Krishan